# how to connect googleapis with several accounts oauth2client in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

When I am logged into my google account via googleapis (oauth2Client), I have access to all my information from another web browser on which I am not logged in.
In fact, you cannot have multiple accounts.

I tried following the doc https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#oauth2-client

```js
oauth2Client;
    scopes;
    drive;

    googleExtensions;

    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param client_id google
     * @param client_secret google
     * @param redirect_url
     * @param scopes authorization asked to the user
     */
    constructor(client_id, client_secret, redirect_url, scopes) {
        this.oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_url);
        this.scopes = scopes;
        this.drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: this.oauth2Client});
    }

    /**
     *
     * @returns authentication url from Google
     */
    authenticate() {
        return this.oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
            access_type: 'offline',
            scope: this.scopes
        });

    }





    /** 
    * sets the access and refresh tokens in the oauth2 client
    * @param code authorization code from Google
    *
    */
    async getTokens(code, res) {
        try {
            const {tokens} = await this.oauth2Client.getToken(code)
            this.oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);console.log('Google token is : ', tokens)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error ', error);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats oauth2 its authorization not authentication.  Its not login.  Im not sure i Understand your question.  Unless you store the refresh token for the user somewhere say in a session var your going to have to ask for authorization every time.

Comment: so how can  i add  an session authentication with  googleapis

Comment: google apis doesn't use signin authentication.    It uses oauth2 authorization you need authorization to access the users data.